# How to populate other attributes when using powershell 2.0 new-aduser?

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0

When trying to create users from a file I get an error when -otherAttributes @{} is added to ps script. I am new to powershell and can not get it to work. Any guidance is appreciated. This is My code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$OU = 'ou=Staging OU, dc=Domain, dc=net'
$usrfile = "\\servername\testuser.csv"

Import-Csv $usrfile | 
ForEach-Object {
     New-ADUser -SamAccountName $_.samaccountname -UserPrincipalName $_.Userprincipalname -Name $_.Name -DisplayName $_.displayname -GivenName $_.givenname -Surname $_.sn -Initials $_.initials -Title $_.title -OtherName $_.middlename `
-Description $_.description -Department $_.department -EmployeeID $_.employeeid -Path $OU -Country $_.c `
-OtherAttributes @{departmentNumber=$user.departmentnumber;localeID=$user.localid;extensionAttribute1=$user.extensionAttribute1;employeeType=$user.employeetype} `
-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $true `
-PasswordNeverExpires $false -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -PassThru 
    } > Import.log
```

Comment: The $user was a oversight going through several iterations of code. udated code: 
-OtherAttributes @{departmentNumber=$_.departmentnumber;localeID=$_.localid;extensionAttribute1=$_.extensionAttribute1;employeeType=$_.employeetype}       gives error:  An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At D:\scripts\crtadusr.ps1:17 char:22
+ Import-Csv $impfile | <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement

Comment: import error corrected. The real error for this post is ;            
+ -OtherAttributes <<<<  @{departmentNumber=$_.departmentnumber;localeID=$_.loc
alid;extensionAttribute1=$_.extensionAttribute1;employeeType=$_.employeetype} `
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory
   .Management.Commands.NewADUser

Answer (score 2):

The parameter "-otherAttributes @{}" fails in my AD. I found other way change this value in AD.

Try with this:

```
PS> Set-ADuser -identity joseiba -Clear 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress'
PS> Set-ADuser -identity joseiba -Add @{'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress'='4213@grupofibratel.com'}
```

BR

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all your $'s as $_... when accessing the object in the current loop iteration. I see some aren't.

Comment: I added some info about my issue by add comment. I don't really know how to use this page. Your comments will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you left out your ' around the ldapdisplayname for the otherattributes

@{departmentNumber=$user.departmentnumber;
should be: @{'departmentNumber'=$user.departmentnumber;

you need the ' around each ldapdisplayname in otherattributes..
just fought this myself dealing with the notes field